# How to print same lines multiple times with variables changed using Sed/Awk/ anything?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, python

a. Have set of lines as given below.

```
cr_v8_sel0 : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel0 {
   ignore_bins ig_v8_sel0 = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel0) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]}; 
}
```

b. I wanted to print the same set of lines multiple times with the decimal~string changed from sel0 to sel31.

c. For Eg: Note: sel0 is the lines is changed to sel1 and printed. And need from sel0 till sel31.

```
cr_v8_sel0 : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel0 {
   ignore_bins ig_v8_sel0 = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel0) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]}; 
}
cr_v8_sel1 : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel1 {
   ignore_bins ig_v8_sel0 = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel1) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]}; 
}
```

d. Can we do it in some for loop fashion to print them all ? rather than typing in hands ? using sed or awk or any script command ?

Comment: In your example, one of the instances of `sel0` in the second group was left unchanged.  Was that intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{print; for (i=1;i<=31;i++) {x=$0; gsub(/sel0/, "sel" i, x); print x;}}' RS="" file
```

For example, and limited to 3 repetitions:

```
$ awk '{print; for (i=1;i<=3;i++) {x=$0; gsub(/sel0/, "sel" i, x); print x;}}' RS="" file
cr_v8_sel0 : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel0 {
   ignore_bins ig_v8_sel0 = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel0) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]}; 
}
cr_v8_sel1 : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel1 {
   ignore_bins ig_v8_sel1 = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel1) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]}; 
}
cr_v8_sel2 : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel2 {
   ignore_bins ig_v8_sel2 = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel2) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]}; 
}
cr_v8_sel3 : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel3 {
   ignore_bins ig_v8_sel3 = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel3) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]}; 
}
```

#### How it works

- `print`

  This prints out the original version with `sel0`.
- `for (i=1;i<=31;i++) {x=$0; gsub(/sel0/, "sel" i, x); print x;`

  This loops over `i` from 1 to 31, makes the substitutions and prints the result.
- `RS=""`

  This tells awk to read an entire paragraph at a time.  Since your source has no blank lines, this has the effect of reading your entire sources at once.

#### Multiline version

```
awk '
  {
     print
     for (i=1;i<=31;i++)
     {
       x=$0
       gsub(/sel0/, "sel" i, x)
       print x;
     }
   }
   ' RS="" file
```

Comment: That was freaking awesome ! Appreciate that timely response and it works great !

Comment: To simplify `for (i=0;i<=31;i++) {gsub("sel[0-9]+", "sel" i); print;}`

Answer (score 3):

With a here document:

```
for i in {0..31}; do 
cat << EOF
cr_v8_sel${i} : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel${i} {
   ignore_bins ig_v8_sel${i} = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel${i}) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]}; 
}
EOF
done
```

Note that if you use this method, you need to be a careful that there is nothing else in the here-document that might get expanded by the shell (in this case, things like `{[0:3],[5:$]}` look like they might be, but in fact aren't - at least not in bash). An essentially similar (but safer) approach using the `envsubst` command from GNU `gettext` can substitute *only* the desired index, as follows:

1. create an environment variable `i` for the index

   ```
   export i
   ```
2. create a template file with the desired index replaced by variable `i`

   ```
   $ cat template
   cr_v8_sel${i} : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel${i} {
      ignore_bins ig_v8_sel${i} = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel${i}) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]};
   }
   ```
3. loop over values of `i` substituting *only* the value of `i`

   ```
   for i in {0..31}; do envsubst '$i' < template; done
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Make an input file *sel.txt*, (nothing fancy, only what the OP had with no changes), run a `bash` loop, and use `sed` in there to do the work:

```
echo "cr_v8_sel0 : cross cp_v8_en, cp_sel0 {
   ignore_bins ig_v8_sel0 = binsof(cp_v8_en) && binsof(cp_sel0) intersect {[0:3],[5:$]}; 
}" > sel.txt

for f in {0..31} ; do sed 's/sel0/sel'$f'/g' sel.txt ; done
```